# Set white background for a png instead of transparency with OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

I have a OpenCv Image likewise;

```
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
```

Then with the following code piece, I want to remove the transparency and set a White background.

```
source_img = cv2.cvtColor(opencvImage[:, :, :3], cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
source_mask = opencvImage[:,:,3]  * (1 / 255.0)

background_mask = 1.0 - source_mask

bg_part = (background_color * (1 / 255.0)) * (background_mask)
source_part = (source_img * (1 / 255.0)) * (source_mask)

result_image = np.uint8(cv2.addWeighted(bg_part, 255.0, source_part, 255.0, 0.0))
```

Actually, I am able to set the background white, however, the actual image color is change, as well. 
I believe **COLOR_BGRA2GRAY** methods causes this problem. That's why, I tried to use **IMREAD_UNCHANGED** method, but I have this error : *unsupported color conversion code in function 'cvtColor’*

Btw, I am open to any solution, I just share my code - might need a small fix.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's a basic script that will replace all fully transparent pixels with white and then remove the alpha channel.

```
import cv2
#load image with alpha channel.  use IMREAD_UNCHANGED to ensure loading of alpha channel
image = cv2.imread('your image', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)    

#make mask of where the transparent bits are
trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 0

#replace areas of transparency with white and not transparent
image[trans_mask] = [255, 255, 255, 255]

#new image without alpha channel...
new_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
```

Comment: After doing this and pickling the new_image I can't open it, every program says that the file (picture) is damaged. Size also increases x20

Comment: @AnnaVopureta you may want to use the *imwrite* function to save your image instead of pickling it.

Comment: how to do this in java

Answer (score 4):

All previous answers use binarizing but mask can be non binary. In that case you can use [alpha blending](https://www.learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/) with white background

```
def alpha_blend_with_mask(foreground, background, mask): # modified func from link
    # Convert uint8 to float
    foreground = foreground.astype(float)
    background = background.astype(float)

    # Normalize the mask mask to keep intensity between 0 and 1
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    mask = mask.astype(float) / 255

    # Multiply the foreground with the mask matte
    foreground = cv2.multiply(mask, foreground)

    # Multiply the background with ( 1 - mask )
    background = cv2.multiply(1.0 - mask, background)

    # Add the masked foreground and background.
    return cv2.add(foreground, background).astype(np.uint8)

img_with_white_background = alpha_blend_with_mask(img[..., :3], np.ones_like(clip_img) * 255, img[..., 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know exactly what that error is, but I was testing just now a possible solution for you. Even it is in C++, I guess you can convert it easily to python.

```
 /* Setting data info */
std::string test_image_path = "Galicia.png";

/* General variables */
cv::namedWindow("Input image", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Input image R", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Input image G", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Input image B", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Input image A", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::namedWindow("Output image", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

/* Process */
cv::Mat test_image = cv::imread(test_image_path, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
std::cout << "Image type: " << test_image.type() << std::endl;

// Split channels of the png files
std::vector<cv::Mat> pngChannels(4);
cv::split(test_image, pngChannels);

cv::imshow("Input image", test_image);
cv::imshow("Input image R", pngChannels[0]);
cv::imshow("Input image G", pngChannels[1]);
cv::imshow("Input image B", pngChannels[2]);
cv::imshow("Input image A", pngChannels[3]);

// Set to 255(white) the RGB channels where the Alpha channel(mask) is 0(transparency)
pngChannels[0].setTo(cv::Scalar(255), pngChannels[3]==0);
pngChannels[1].setTo(cv::Scalar(255), pngChannels[3]==0);
pngChannels[2].setTo(cv::Scalar(255), pngChannels[3]==0);

// Merge again the channels
cv::Mat test_image_output;
cv::merge(pngChannels, test_image_output);

// Show the merged channels.
cv::imshow("Output image", test_image_output);

// For saving with changes, conversion is needed.
cv::cvtColor(test_image_output, test_image_output, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
cv::imwrite("Galicia_mod.png", test_image_output);
```

I complement the code with this screenshot that may help you to understand better my solution:

[image]

Best Wishes,
Arritmic

Comment: thanks for sharing. This is the logic I follow, as well, and you described it in a clear way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the answer by @user1269942 leave black edges and makes an unnecessary contour around the image.
I needed to fill the background to this image
[This was the image I needed to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AShVJ.png)

[this is the image after following the steps in accepted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axg9p.png)
However If we do masking based on a threshold value we can reduce that unnecessary contour based on how much we choose threshold value. I have choosen 75 in my case.
So instead of `trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 0`
If we do

```py
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
ret, trans_mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)    
trans_mask = trans_mask == 0    

def fillColor(imageFile, color):    
  image = cv2.imread(imageFile, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)    
  #trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 0
  img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
  ret, trans_mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  trans_mask = trans_mask == 0
  image[trans_mask] = color    
  new_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)    
  return new_img
```

[The Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0nwe.png)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me..

```
# import cv2
# #load image with alpha channel.  use IMREAD_UNCHANGED to ensure loading of alpha channel
image = cv2.imread('/content/test1.jpg')    

#make mask of where the transparent bits are
transp_mask = image[:,:,:3] == 0
transp_mask = image[:,:,:3] == 1 # swap 

#replace areas of transparency with white and not transparent
image[transp_mask] = [100]


#new image without alpha channel...
new_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('testingnew.jpg',new_img)  converted to binary img
print(new_img.shape)
plt.imshow(new_img)
```

transparent image

[image]

output

[image]

output2

[image]

real img

[image]