# how to convert alpha channel of the image to white color using gocv?

Tags: opencv, go

How do i convert alpha channel of the image to white color using gocv? Sorry, I would'nt find the documentation.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {
    inputs := "test.png"
    img := gocv.IMRead(inputs, gocv.IMReadUnchanged)
    defer img.Close()
    if img.Empty() {
        fmt.Printf("cannot read image %s\n", inputs)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // how to convert alpha channel of the image to white color
    gocv.Split(img)
}
```

Comment: i guess you want to translate those answers to go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732747/set-white-background-for-a-png-instead-of-transparency-with-opencv/53737420