# What does "image[:,:,3]" mean in Python/OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I have come across this line of code from an answer to a stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53737420):

```py
trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 0
```

This creates a mask from an OpenCV image. I am wondering how the syntax for `image[:,:,3] == 0` works.

I know that `list[:]` basically makes a copy of a list, but I was unaware that you could pass a tuple (which is what `:,:,3` is, I believe) to index a list. And then comparing this to a 0?

Comment: Very likely extracting an alpha channel (the 4th channel) from a BGRA/RGBA image. Then it compares each element with 0, and gives you an array of boolean-likes representing the result of the comparison. Since alpha==0 generally means "fully transparent", it will give you mask of all fully transparent pixels (as the comment in source owuld suggest).

Comment: What you probably want to read up on is numpy array indexing.

Comment: `image` is a numpy array, not a list.  It handles the tuple just fine.  It's 3d, so the tuple is selecting a value on the third dimension.  For arrays loaded from images that most like is one of the color channels.

Comment: @DanMašek @hpaulj I understand *what* it does, but how does it work? How can I pass a `:` to the __getitem__ method?

Answer (score -1):

When a list-like object is indexed, the `__getitem__` method is called. One can create a simple class that shows you what is passed to that method:

```
class Inspector:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key()

i = Inspector()
i[:,:,3] # => (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), 3)
```

Which means that the `:` is represented by a `slice` instance.

The same goes with the comparison to 0: Python calls the **eq** operator. So the `__getitem__` call in the question will return another numpy array, which implements the `__eq__` method, which in turn realizes that it gets passed a scalar value and will create a certain data structure representing a mask.

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([
  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
  [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
  [[21,22,23],[24,25,26],[27,28,29]]
])
arr[:,:,2]
# =>
#array([[ 3,  6,  9],
#       [13, 16, 19],
#       [23, 26, 29]])
mask = arr[:,:,2] == 16
# =>
#array([[False, False, False],
#       [False,  True, False],
#       [False, False, False]])
```

So the mask is just a numpy array that contains boolean values.